# Form action doesn't submit hard-coded variable

Tags: php

I have a form with the code below, which sends form option choice as "project" variable.

```
<form name="projects" method="get" action="\web\ttt.php?str=aaa" >
```

However, the output always looks this:

/ttt.php?Projects=3  //there is str=aaa missing which I defined in the form action.

How to let it pass this variable?

Thanks

Comment: Could you post the complete HTML for your form?

Comment: Also, use forward slashes: "/web/ttt.php"; backward slashes are not valid in this context and are not understood by most browsers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using GET as method all query params in the action attribute are discarded and the items in the form are used instead, either change to POST instead of GET or add a hidden field with the name 'str' and value 'aaa' to achieve what your are trying to do.

Answer (score 5):

You should use an hidden input control to pass variables with a form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="myname" value="myvalue" />
```

Comment: It works, but the result will be in the POST data, not the GET data.

Comment: I mean, in $_POST, not in $_GET.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="projects" method="get" action="\web\ttt.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="str" value="aaa" />
    // Other form stuff
</form>
```